# Visual Studio Show Padlock Near Tab and from Metadata When Viewing Code Source from Razor

Tags: visual-studio, razor

Trying to view source code related to a method that is being used in a Razor code block. However, when I right-click on method to view the definition, it takes me to the page where the source code is, but it doesn't actually show the code in the associated procedure. It only shows the procedure name. And, in that page's tab, it has a little pad lock next to it with the words "from metadata".  How can I view the source code

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the padlock version was referring to the compiled dll file. For some reason the original removed all the code behind files to a different location and the application was only able to refer to the dll as a library reference. Had to rebuild all the references and that fixed the problem.